# Bootstrap - Columns will not stack vertically on xs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I must be missing something obvious here, but I am a beginner with Bootstrap and I have no idea what it could be. I'm trying to get this picture and the adjacent paragraph to stack vertically on xs screens. No matter what I do, they just line up alongside each other, pushing the picture to the edge of the screen. Here's a picture of what is happening, and my code.

[image: Picture of improper stacking]

```
        <div class="row para-text vertical-align">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-md-push-4">
                <p>text....</p>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-md-pull-8">
                <img class="img-full" src="img/artesia1.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here are the css styles I've added, in case those are causing problems

```
.para-text {
padding:15px;
}

.vertical-align {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're implementing Flexbox. If you want to lay a set of information out horizontally where the screen size permits, but collapse the contents horizontally where it does not. You need to add the wrap value to the flex-flow property. (i.e., `flex-flow: row wrap;`).

Comment: Here's a basic flex example for you. http://jsfiddle.net/rp8y208k/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend not using your css classes that you posted. When I did a simple example with your html code but no css, it seems to work fine:

Please see: http://www.bootply.com/GCu0vDtk6K

Note: I also removed your:

```
<div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my problem was using Flexbox. I've opted out of using it and am going to find a different way to vertical align the image so that I can have better browser support.

Comment: umm..did u get to review my answer above?

Comment: Yeah, I did what you suggested. I took out the css class vertical-align (which was implementing flex) and deleted the clearfix.